# How to set multicast address to receive from directly

Tags: python, sockets, networking, multicast

I have a server(Running on Windows 10) and client (Running on Raspbian) communicating with each other and I'm having issues receiving multicast data from a client device.

I believe I've isolated the problem on my server. The problem is that when I set up the receive socket on my server, the socket only receives multicast data from it's only IP address only, the multicast address is not added even though I've configured it to do so. Currently the code I use to set up my receive socket is...

```
def _init_recv_socket(self):
    self.recieve_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    self.recieve_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    self.recieve_socket.bind(('', MCAST_PORT))
    mreq = struct.pack("4sl", socket.inet_aton(MCAST_GRP), socket.INADDR_ANY)
    self.recieve_socket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
```

I read online that using `socket.INADDR_ANY` is dangerous because it won't always set up to the correct interface. I called

```
print socket.gethostbyname_ex(socket.gethostname())
```

and it displayed what address I was receiving from and my multicast address was not displayed. The output was:

```
('MSI', [], ['192.168.99.1])
```

I found online how to set the multicast and interface address only getting the same output:

```
group = socket.inet_atons(MCAST_GRP)
iface = socket.inet_atons('192.168.99.1')
self.recieve_socket.setsocketopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, group+iface)
```

My multicast still isn't showing up when running the gethostbyname command.

I'm stuck and not sure how to get my server working to recieve multicast data...

Note: The same code works fine on my raspberry pi, just not on my windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Multicast not working between two different computers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38364835/python-multicast-not-working-between-two-different-computers)